# Customizing Constructors in 1 line of code

Tags: javascript, constructor, custom-controls

May I ask for some help?  I'm doing Codeacademy, and I'm thoroughly stuck.  I'm following the instructions to the best of my ability but would be extremely grateful if any could offer assistance to my problem(s).

Instructions
Notice that without the constructor, it takes us 3 lines of code to make harry_potter, an object that represents Harry Potter book 1.

Then in line 7 we introduce a constructor for a Book object, where we pass in the pages and author properties as parameters.

Use this constructor to make the_hobbit, a book by "J.R.R. Tolkien" with 320 pages. Notice by using the constructor you can do this in only one line instead of three!

```
// 3 lines required to make harry_potter
var harry_potter = new Object();
harry_potter.pages = 350;
harry_potter.author = "J.K. Rowling";

// A custom constructor for book
function Book (pages, author) {
    this.pages = pages;
    this.author = author;
}

// Use our new constructor to make the_hobbit in one line
var the_hobbit = new Book ("J.R.R. Tokien", 320);

// That last line of code is my own, and when I submit the code I receive this          error/warning:

//Oops, try again. Make sure that the_hobbit's author is J.R.R. Tolkien by passing it     as the first argument to the Book constructor.
```

This is the "output" when submitting code:

"J.K. Rowling"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var the_hobbit = new Book ("J.R.R. Tokien", 320);
```

Tolkien, not Tokien. :)

```
var the_hobbit = new Book ("J.R.R. Tolkien", 320);
```

Maybe that typo is in your actual code?

Comment: OH MAN!! THAT MIGHT HAVE BEEN IT TOO!!  Oh my gosh just 1 character can slay my greatest efforts lol... Either way you've been a gentleman and a professor, and on both accounts I've taken value.

Comment: Seems to me you missed the character, then reversed your call. Remember to look for the simple things first. Syntax, spelling. I tend to type as little as possible and let the IDE do most of the finishing for mew. lol

Comment: Both indeed.  Thanks very much for your help again, thanks to JacobM as well as he was to the rescue nearly the moment I submitted the question!!  

I could get used to a stellar community like this, if everyone here on Stackoverflow is as awesome as you gents, I'm thrilled to be here!!

Answer (score 1):

You were so close! You've just got the parameters switched.

You want

```
var the_hobbit = new Book (320, "J.R.R. Tokien");
```

since the function specifies `Book(pages, author)`.  You had been doing `Book(author, pages)`.

Your basic whoopsie.

Comment: I can't thank you enough... for some reason, I THINK I had that before, but it was telling me "Error, make sure you pass the_hobbit author as J.R.R. Tolkien first. Which screwed me all up, none the less thank you so much, I was seriously flustered and ready to just give it a rest for the day. 

Happy to be proceeding : )

Comment: Yeah, it looks like their error message doesn't match their sample constructor.  So you're not the only one who made a bobble.  Computers are so picky! :)